# Get process GDI object count

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, autoit

I'm looking to get the count of GDIObjects of certain processes.

Using Windows XP it was possible with user32.dll's `getGUIResources()`, but on Windows Vista and -7 it returns `0` for processes running under `..\System`.

How to get the GDI object count?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code. It works for me on Windows 7. I thought: "If task manager can do it, then I can do it". I'm not sure if it requires administrative privileges, but I have tested *with*.

In the example I get information from winlogon.exe which runs under SYSTEM credentials.

Output on my machine:

```
Process ID: 584
Process handle: 0x00000198
GDI objects: 6
```

which fits with what task manager was showing.
[image: winlogon.exe showing SYSTEM and 6 GDI objects]

```
#RequireAdmin

#include <WinAPI.au3>

Const $PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION  = 0x1000

; Get ID to process
$id = ProcessExists("winlogon.exe")
If @error Then
    ConsoleWrite("Error in ProcessExists: " & @error & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf
ConsoleWrite("Process ID: " & $id & @CRLF)

; Get handle to process from the ID
$handle = _WinAPI_OpenProcess($PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, False, $id)
If @error Then
    ConsoleWrite("Error in _WinAPI_OpenProcess: " & @error & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf
ConsoleWrite("Process handle: " & $handle & @CRLF)

; Get number of GDI objects via GetGuiResources
$gdiCount = _WinAPI_GetGuiResources(0, $handle)
If @error Then
    ConsoleWrite("Error in _WinAPI_GetGuiResources: " & @error & @CRLF)
    Exit
EndIf
ConsoleWrite("GDI objects: " & $gdiCount & @CRLF)

; Close handle to process
_WinAPI_CloseHandle($handle)
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably something about access rights, your script not being able to access processes with higher privileges. I'm not sure here though, but give this a try: Run your script with administrator privileges by adding this to your script:

```
#RequireAdmin
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried as you recommended. But as far as I can see: no chance to get information about those (also with admin rights). Programs like ProcessExplorer seem to have no solution there, too.